# manage wordpress and subversion

Tags: php, svn, wordpress, magento, auto-update

I have a large site w/ magento and wordpress.  The only access I have to get files from my local environment to production server is via FTP.  I'm struggling how to get wordpress updated and changes committed into my repository.  When I run the automatic WP update from admin, entire directories are wiped out and re-created....I lose those .svn directories when this happens.  If I update on the production server and pull changes down I'm not quite sure what files have been removed so I can get them deleted from my repository.

anyone have ideas how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the documentation : http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress (section "Manual update")

if you want to preserve your .svn dirs, use svn del and svn add commands to replace files.